# How to fix non-working ethernet under Linux, with RX permanently increasing?

Tags: linux, ethernet, ifconfig

I have a system with the latest Linux Mint. An ethernet cable which yields internet with no special action from me under Windows 8.1 is detected under Linux, but does not seem to work. Running ifconfig repeatedly shows me the OS keeps downloading mysterious packets. ping gives no result.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thank you for your remark. I have changed the topic of the title to match a question layout.

Comment: Still need more information.  Are you using DHCP?  Does it acquire an IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Running `tcpdump -i <interface name>` Will tell you where the traffic is coming from.  I would double check the current route settings for the interface with `netstat -rn`